# Add external libraries in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I want to use some external jQuery libraries in my Angular project.

I added these libraries inside `index.html` file, but they are not working. I also added my `.js` files in `angular.json`, but the problem still exists. I add libraries like this:

```js
<!-- CUSTOM JS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.app.js"></script>
```

Actually the code in this js file is not reachable. It seems Angular does not understand it to go and run that specific function in this file.

I expect a menu item shows its sub menus but the jQuery code does not work in Angular.

Comment: Angular uses Webpack.  You should be `import`ing your dependencies, not adding them as plain scripts.  Consider reading this: [Workspace npm dependencies](https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages#dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

As you use Angular, you probably also use the angular/cli.
In that case, just add your file in the `angular.json` file like :

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
  ],
```

This will let angular import your external lib in the end bundle.

You will find more informations in the official documentation :
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Comment: my external libraries are in assets folder. how to import them?

Comment: It's recommended to use a package manager. You can use angular cli to import them with `ng add` see https://angular.io/cli/add or directly through npm with `npm install`(https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install). Without package manager, just change the path to the one you have.